# PHP set date('w') function return Sunday as 7, instead of 0

Tags: php, date, time

From official manual , the `date ('w')` shows the current date as

```
0 = Sunday
1 = Monday

.....

6 = Saturday
```

The problem is , without any further modification , are there any way (eg. set parameter?) to specific the Sunday as 7 instead of 0 ? thanks

Comment: Why would you want to change around the pre-set value for something so small?

Comment: You can use `'N'` instead of `'w'`... or you can just calculate the value you need: `((date('w')+6)%7)+1`

Comment: @jcsanyi or just `date('w') ?: 7`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to use `'N'` format specifier for [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function:

```
date('N')
```

---

> Description: ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP
> 5.1.0)
>
> Example returned values: 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)

Answer (score 7):

```
date('N')
```

**N** - The ISO-8601 numeric representation of a day (1 for Monday, 7 for Sunday)